# copy over data from one work book into another workbook without using VBA

Tags: excel

I have two seperate workbooks. Workbook A and Workbook B. When I type in the info in cell O4 on workbook A I want the info to automatically populate in Cell B4 on workbook b and I don't want to use VBA

Comment: "I don't want to use VBA" makes this question off-topic for StackOverflow. Questions about general software use are not appropriate here; there are other [se] sites available that may be more suitable. In this case, that would appear to be [su]. Good luck. The [help] has more information about the types of question that are appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making cross-workbook links. In Workbook B cell B4 type `=` (don't press enter) then select Workbook A cell O4

Comment: Thanks! It worked and I saw the formula. I feel like such a dunce! I knew how to do it the whole time!